# javascript parse json multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My JSON data

```
{
    "data":[{
        "company_name":"ABC Corp",
        "main_phone":"555-555-5555",
        "comp_url":"www.abccorp.com",
        "fac_type":"Data Center",
        "office":"NJ",
        "client_info":[{
            "client_name":"Tom Stevens",
            "client_name":"Mike Stages"
        }]
    }]
}
```

How do I parse to get the client_info and put it in a loop using JavaScript? I want to display the information as such:

```
Client Name: Tom Stevens
Client Name: Mike Stages
```

I've written this but it returns "undefined"

```
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +        
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Client Name:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.client_name + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
```

Comment: What does `d` represent in your second code block? To get a useful answer, you may want to consider including the entire function for which your second code block is the return value.

Comment: the part of `"client_info":[{...` is not valid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, with two times the same property?

Comment: @NinaScholz: Just saw that. It *is* valid in JavaScript (no idea about JSON; probably, and jsonlint.com says it is), but it's not ***useful***. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ok valid yes, but it does not make the wanted result possible, with the values of both properties.

Comment: @NinaScholz: I fixed my answer to address that, and to add a live example.

Answer (score 2):

You do not parse an object.  The data is in an array so you need to reference the first index

```
yourObj.data[0].client_info[0].client_name
```

Next issue is your object has two keys that are the same so there is no way to get both.

Your object needs to be an array of objects

```
"client_info":[
    {"client_name":"Tom Stevens"},
    {"client_name":"Mike Stages"}
]
```

Now you would be able to loop over the names and read each one and build a row in the table for each one.

```js
var d = {
  "data": [{
    "company_name": "ABC Corp",
    "main_phone": "555-555-5555",
    "comp_url": "www.abccorp.com",
    "fac_type": "Data Center",
    "office": "NJ",
    "client_info": [
      { "client_name": "Tom Stevens" },
      { "client_name": "Mike Stages" }
    ]
  }]
};

var names = "";
for (var i = 0; i < d.data.length; i++) {
  var clients = d.data[i].client_info;
  for (var j = 0; j < clients.length; j++) {
    names += "<tr><th>Client Name:</th><td>" + clients[j].client_name + "</td></tr>";
  }
}

var table = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;"></tbody>' + names + '</tbody></table>';

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = table;
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it doesn't do what you want.

You need to go back and look at your JSON.

The biggest problem with it is "client_info"  you have it as an Array with 1 element of type object, but that object defines the same attribute twice.

I think it should be changed to an Array with 2 elements each with there own client_name

In the "working" example below, you will note you only get "Mike Stages" as he overwrites "Tom Stevens" and that happens in the data definition, not in the code.

```js
"data":[{
    "company_name":"ABC Corp",
    "main_phone":"555-555-5555",
    "comp_url":"www.abccorp.com",
    "fac_type":"Data Center",
    "office":"NJ",
    "client_info":[{
        "client_name":"Tom Stevens",
        "client_name":"Mike Stages"
        }]
    }]
};

var company = theData.data[0];
var clientInfo = company.client_info;

for(var i=0; i < clientInfo.length; i++) {
 console.log('<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +        
             '<tr>' +
             '<td>Client Name:</td>' +
             '<td>' + clientInfo[i].client_name + '</td>' +
             '</tr>' +
             '</table>')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to deal with the issue that `client_info` is an array containing just a single object, and you've *repeated* the property name `client_name` in that object. That means (in JavaScript) the second one overwrites the first.

You probably meant `client_info` to have *two* objects in it:

```
...
client_info: [
    {"client_name":"Tom Stevens"},
    {"client_name":"Mike Stages"}
]
...
```

Then, since it's an array, you'd need a loop (`for`, `forEach`, `map`, etc.), and within the loop you'd need to use an index (0, 1, etc.)

So for instance, if I assume `d` is referencing that entire structure (and that you've parsed it, so you're not dealing with JSON anymore, just array/sobjects):

```
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
       d.data[0].client_info.map(function(client) {
            return '<tr>' +
                   '<td>Client Name:</td>' +
                   '<td>' + client.client_name + '</td>' +
                   '</tr>';
       }).join("") +
       '</table>';
```

Note that `data` is also an array. In the above, I'm assuming you're doing this just for the *first* entry in `data` (hence `d.data[0]`). If you want multiple entries from `data`, you'll need another loop around that one.

**Live example:**

```js
document.body.innerHTML = test({
    "data":[{
        "company_name":"ABC Corp",
        "main_phone":"555-555-5555",
        "comp_url":"www.abccorp.com",
        "fac_type":"Data Center",
        "office":"NJ",
        "client_info":[
            {"client_name":"Tom Stevens"},
            {"client_name":"Mike Stages"}
        ]
    }]
});
function test(d) {
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
           d.data[0].client_info.map(function(client) {
                return '<tr>' +
                       '<td>Client Name:</td>' +
                       '<td>' + client.client_name + '</td>' +
                       '</tr>';
           }).join("") +
           '</table>';
};
```

Comment: I've updated to address the issue of the repeated property name.

Answer (score -1):

You can access client name like this...plz chk...your code

"object.data[0].client_info[0].client_name"

Answer (score -2):

Thank you everyone for your contribution! After taking bits and pieces of what everyone has written I figured it out!

```
{"data":[{
"company_name":"ABC Corp",
"main_phone":"555-555-5555",
"comp_url":"www.abccorp.com",
"fac_type":"Data Center",
"office":"NJ",
"client":[
{"client_name":"Mike Stages"},
{"client_name":"THIS WORKS!!!"}
    ]
}]}
```

JavaScript:

```
    p._formatDetails = function(d) {


            var ht_val ='<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
            //alert(d.client.length);
            var d_len = d.client.length;
            var i = 0;
            alert(d_len);
            while( i < d_len){

                ht_val +='<tr><td>Client Name:</td>';
                ht_val +='<td>' + d.client[i].client_name + '</td></tr>';
                i++;
            }
            ht_val +='</table>';
            //alert(ht_val);
            return ht_val;

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. This was extremely helpful